# Difference between &a, *(&a) and *(*(&a))

Tags: c++

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 7;
    int *a = &i;
    cout << &a << endl; //This Line
    cout << *(&a) << endl; //This Line
    cout << *(*(&a)) << endl; //This Line
}
```

**Outputs**

```
0x6a12fffdf8
0x6a12fffe00
7
```

Hi all. I am not very sure what the difference between these three lines is (see code comments). I know the first line prints the address, but I am not sure about the other two.

Comment: `*` and `&` cancel each other out.

Comment: `3`? You sure this is the code you are actually running?

Comment: The last output should be `7` not `3`?

Comment: `*` dereferences the address, i.e. looks at what is at that address. `&a` is the address of a pointer to an `int` so `*&a` will print the address of the `int`. `**&a`, will dereference the pointer to the `int` printing that in the process

Comment: Okay, I understand what is going on now. Thanks, everyone. I have also corrected the output.

Answer (score 4):

Lets go line by line:

```
int i = 7;
```

`i` is an `int` initialized with the integer literal `7`.

```
int *a = &i;
```

`a` is a pointer, `int*`, and is initialized with the address of `i`. `&` is the addressof operator here.

```
cout << &a << endl; //This Line
```

`a` itself is also stored at some memory address. The addressof operator applied to `a` yields that memory address.

```
cout << *(&a) << endl; //This Line
```

Here `*` is the dereference operator. `&`, addressof, and `*`, dereference, cancel each other. This line prints the value of `a`, the address of `i`.

```
cout << *(*(&a)) << endl; //This Line
```

We already know that `*(&a)` is the value of `a`, the memory address of `i`. Applying the dereference operator to the address of `i` yields the value of `i`.

---

In memory it looks like this:

```
 address: &a             &i == a
          0x6a12fffdf8   0x6a12fffe00

 value:   a              i == *a
          0x6a12fffe00   7
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some data, `int i = 7;`. This integer is stored in memory (specifically, the stack).

You have a pointer, `a`, that points to (addresses) this memory `int *a = &i;` because the `int *` datatype means an int pointer, and `&i` means the "address of i".

Your pointer is also stored in memory (again, the stack). You can get *its* address in much the same way, using `&a`.

`cout << &a << endl;` therefore prints the address of the pointer, `a`.

To dereference (get the value of) a pointer, you use `*`.

`cout << *(&a) << endl;` therefore prints the dereferenced value of the address of `a`, which is the value of `a` (and therefore the address of `i`).

Your final line  `cout << *(*(&a)) << endl;` reads as

"Print the dereferenced value of the dereferenced value of the address of `a`", which is simply `i`.

Answer (score 0):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the expression:

```
&a  //this gives us the address of the variable `a`
```

The above expression gives us the address of variable `a`.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the expression:

```
*(&a)  //this gives us the data to which `&a` points which is nothing but the address of variable i
```

The above expression gives us the data to which `&a` points. But from case 1 we already know that `&a` is nothing but the address of variable `a`. Thus, `*(&a)` is the same as the address of variable `i`.

##### Case 3

Here we consider the expression:

```
*(*(&a))
```

The above expression gives us the data to which `*(&a)` points. Since we already know from case 2 that `*(&a)` gives us the address of variable `i`, this implies that `*(*(&a))`  gives us `i` itself.